# Why is the Java 8 'Collector' class designed in this way?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

We know Java 8 introduces a new Stream API and `java.util.stream.Collector` is the interface to define how to aggregate/collect the data stream.

However, the Collector interface is designed like this:

```
public interface Collector<T, A, R> {
    Supplier<A> supplier();
    BiConsumer<A, T> accumulator();
    BinaryOperator<A> combiner();
    Function<A, R> finisher();
}
```

Why is it not designed like the following?

```
public interface Collector<T, A, R> {
    A supply();
    void accumulate(A accumulator, T value);
    A combine(A left, A right);
    R finish(A accumulator);
}
```

The latter one is much easier to implement. What were the consideration to design it as the former one?

Comment: is all about OOP and structure consistent , just simply guessing.

Comment: Note that you can implement an abstract base class that adapts to the second pattern.

Comment: @Thilo I think both first and second pattern can be adapted in each direction. I just think the second one is more intuitive.

Comment: `much easier to implement` not really. Instead of having your function in `supply`, you return a lambda that calls that function, it is not much more.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually it was originally designed similarly to what you propose. See [the early implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/annotate/49e48ab36d99/src/share/classes/java/util/stream/Collector.java) in project lambda repository (`makeResult` is now `supplier`). It was later [updated](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/lambda/lambda/jdk/rev/221c5b4f706c) to the current design. I believe, the rationale of such update is to simplify collector combinators. I did not find any specific discussion on this topic, but my guess is supported by the fact that `mapping` collector appeared in the same changeset. Consider the implementation of `Collectors.mapping`:

```
public static <T, U, A, R>
Collector<T, ?, R> mapping(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper,
                           Collector<? super U, A, R> downstream) {
    BiConsumer<A, ? super U> downstreamAccumulator = downstream.accumulator();
    return new CollectorImpl<>(downstream.supplier(),
                               (r, t) -> downstreamAccumulator.accept(r, mapper.apply(t)),
                               downstream.combiner(), downstream.finisher(),
                               downstream.characteristics());
}
```

This implementation needs to redefine `accumulator` function only, leaving `supplier`, `combiner` and `finisher` as is, so you don't have additional indirection when calling `supplier`, `combiner` or `finisher`: you just call directly the functions returned by the original collector. It's even more important with `collectingAndThen`:

```
public static<T,A,R,RR> Collector<T,A,RR> collectingAndThen(Collector<T,A,R> downstream,
                                                            Function<R,RR> finisher) {
    // ... some characteristics transformations ...
    return new CollectorImpl<>(downstream.supplier(),
                               downstream.accumulator(),
                               downstream.combiner(),
                               downstream.finisher().andThen(finisher),
                               characteristics);
}
```

Here only `finisher` is changed, but original `supplier`, `accumulator` and `combiner` are used. As `accumulator` is called for every element, reducing the indirection could be pretty important. Try to rewrite `mapping` and `collectingAndThen` with your proposed design and you will see the problem. New JDK-9 collectors like `filtering` and `flatMapping` also benefit from current design.

Answer (score 18):

[Composition is favored over inheritance.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

The first pattern in your question is sort of a module configuration. The implementations of the Collector interface can provide out varying implementations for Supplier, Accumulator, etc. This means **one can compose** Collector implementations from a existing pool of Supplier, Accumulator, etc. implementations. This also helps re-use and two Collectors might use the same Accumulator implementation. The `Stream.collect()` uses the supplied behaviors.

In the second pattern, the Collector implementation has to implement all functions by itself. All kinds of variations would need overriding the parent implementation. Not much scope to re-use, plus code duplication if two collectors have similar logic for a step, for example, accumulation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But for my version, it is also easy to implement a helper wrapper version of Collector.of(....) by these lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

2 related reasons

- **Functional composition** via combinators. (Note you can still do OO composition but look at below point)
- Possibility of framing business logic in **succinct expressive code** via lambda expression or method reference when assignment target is a **functional interface**.

  ****Functional composition****

  Collectors API paves a way for functional composition via combinators .i.e. build small/smallest reusable functionality and combine some of these often in an interesting way into an advanced feature/function.

  ****succinct expressive code****

  Below we are using function pointer (Employee::getSalary) to fill the functionality of mapper from Employee object to int. summingInt fills the logic of adding ints and hence combined together we have sum of salaries written out in a single line of declarative code.

  // Compute sum of salaries of employee
   int total = employees.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.summingInt(**Employee::getSalary**)));